# How to set none for border color of the phone input when using react-phone-number-input

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, input-field, react-phone-number-input

I'm using react-phone-number-input. This is the phone number field:

```
<PhoneInput
    defaultCountry={"CA"}
    placeholder={"Phone"}
    value={phone}
    onChange={(value: string) => {
       setPhone(value);
    }}
/>
```

and the css from:
https://gitlab.com/catamphetamine/react-phone-number-input/-/blob/master/style.css

I set the border and outline of PhoneInputInput to none but it not working when focus.

```
.PhoneInputInput:focus-visible {
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Here's the image of this field:
[image: Phone Input Field]

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on stackblitz or codesandbox as well and paste the link here?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-phone-number-input-2inre7?file=/src/App.js  I've pasted it in codesandbox and it worked correctly. It seems to be caused by the default input of reactjs.

Comment: Did you find an answer to override the default input? I'm encountering the same issue

Comment: @nicoolaslb I add this to the globals.css file:
.input-phone-number input:focus{
    outline: none !important;
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be caused by the default input of reactjs. I added this to the globals.css file:

```
.input-phone-number input:focus{
    outline: none !important;
    border:none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

and use it in the PhoneInput field, then it worked for me:

```
<PhoneInput
    defaultCountry={"CA"}
    placeholder={"Phone"}
    value={phone}
    onChange={(value: string) => {
       setPhone(value);
    }}
    className={"input-phone-number"}
/>
```